# Trouble querying datetime field against today

Tags: sql-server

Can't figure out how to query dates before DateTime field in SQL Server

The Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time is a (datetime2(7), null) format

I've tried the below list and all give me the same error message.

```
Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time >= '2019-09-06T00:00:00.000'

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time >= '09/06/2019 00:00:00 AM'

year(Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time) <= 2019
AND month(Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time) <= 9
AND day(Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time) <= 6

CONVERT(datetime, Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time) < CONVERT(datetime, '2019-09-05 01:23:45.678');  

DATE(Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time) < CONVERT(datetime, '2019-09-05 01:23:45.678');  

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time < convert(datetime, GETDATE())

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time < Convert(Varchar, getdate())

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time < getdate()

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time <= DATE(NOW())

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time <= CURDATE();

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time < NOW()

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time < TODAY()

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time < '20190905'

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time < '2019-09-05 00:00:00.000'

Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time < SYSDATETIME()
```

Every error is the same

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Something isn't adding up. Can you double-check the type of "Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time"? Because it sure seems like it must be a string. Also, can you submit your COMPLETE SQL SELECT statement, and not just the partial WHERE clause? If you execute SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time' … what is the result?

Comment: i couldn't reproduce your concern, see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0a19f729b2a0b6926589a5e7283a9f69 - as pmbAustin also notes i think your job_vehicle... column is a string and one of the rows has some crap in it

Comment: Also note that '2019-09-05 01:23:45.678' is not a valid 'datetime' type... it will never equal anything. It will evaluate to ''2019-09-05 01:23:45.677' instead, due to resolution limitations in the last digit of those milliseconds. Just FYI. If you need the added precision, you need to cast to datetime2. But I think the real problem is you have a non-date-time in your 'Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time' column, and it's not a datetime2 type as you think it is.

Comment: Field is type datetime2(7)

start of query is
SELECT *
FROM Estimate_Data_Table
WHERE
Debtor_Invoice_Date = 'NULL'
AND

Comment: @pmbAustin SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Estimate_Data_Table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Job_Vehicle_Completed_Date_Time' gave me datetime2

Comment: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);` is not sql server syntax.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Estimate_Data_Table WHERE Debtor_Invoice_Date = 'NULL'` That's your error. `Debtor_Invoice_Date` is presumably a `date/time` datatype, and you're comparing it with a literal string `'NULL'`. If you want to check for null the correct syntax is `Debtor_Invoice_Date IS NULL`.